# Is there an another way to call retry funcation except response code equal 400- 500 when i using RequestInterceptor of Alamofire

Tags: swift, authentication, networking, alamofire

I want to refresh the token when it expires, but the server returns 200 not 401 so the retry method will not execute.

Is there a way to manually call retry? Or some other solution？

Comment: Look into Request Interceptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize Alamofire's `.validate` closure to produce an error when certain responses have a 200 status code.

```swift
.validate { request, response, data in
  guard response is token expiration else { return .success(()) }

  return .failure(.responseValidationFailed(.customValidationFailed(error: <your error>)))
}
```

The error your produce here will be available to the retriers later in the pipeline so you can detect token expiration and issue the refresh.